# How to save values in dynamic fields?

Tags: dynamic, inputfield, save

I created a notebook with this line:

```
Grid[{{InputField[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x^2]}}]
```

Then, I filled a certain value instead of "x".

Then, I closed Mathematica and reopened it. Instead of the value I entered, I saw "x" again.

Is there a way to tell Mathematica to save all the values inside input fields with the notebook?

Comment: For global use or for that gui? Fir gui see DynamicModule. In general, Save and friends

Comment: I want that, when I close Mathematica and then re-open it and re-open the same notebook, I will see the same values in the fields (like a spreadsheet)

Comment: Are you planning to use those values outside the gui or is it only supposed to work inside the gui? So have you seen `DynamicModule`?

Comment: What do you mean by "outside the gui" vs "inside the gui"? I only use the notebook..

Comment: In this context it would be the output of a `Grid`. But then you can evaluate `x + 2` anywhere in a notebook and it will use the `x` from the gui as it is not scoped. The latter case is the outside.

Answer (score 3):

As @Kuba says in the comments, use [`DynamicModule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule) with the `SaveDefinitions->True` option:

```
DynamicModule[{x = a},
    Grid[{{InputField[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x^2]}}],
    SaveDefinitions->True
]
```

Comment: `x` will be saved by default, unless `UnsavedVariables` is used. `SaveDefinitions` afects symbols that are not scoped by `DynamicModule` but used inside inner `Dynamics`.